# Django and Postgres transaction rollback

Tags: python, django, postgresql, transactions

I have a piece of code that works in a background process which looks like

```
from django.db import transaction

try:

    <some code>

    transaction.commit()

except Exception, e:

    print e

    transaction.rollback()
```

In a test, I break `<some_code>` with data that causes a database error. The exception is following

```
File "/home/commando/Development/Diploma/streaminatr/stream/testcases/feeds.py", line 261, in testInterrupt

    form.save(self.user1)                                                                                    

File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.5/django/db/transaction.py", line 223, in _autocommit                     

    return func(*args, **kw)                                                                                 

File "/home/commando/Development/Diploma/streaminatr/stream/forms.py", line 99, in save                    

    print(models.FeedChannel.objects.all())                                                                  

File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.5/django/db/models/query.py", line 68, in `__repr__ `                       

    data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])                                                                 

File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.5/django/db/models/query.py", line 83, in `__len__ `                        

    self._result_cache.extend(list(self._iter))                                                              

File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.5/django/db/models/query.py", line 238, in iterator                       

    for row in self.query.results_iter():                                                                    

File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.5/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 287, in results_iter               

    for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):                                                                     

File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.5/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 2369, in execute_sql               

    cursor.execute(sql, params)                                                                              

InternalError: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

This is what I expect. The bad thing is that I still get the same error when I try to access the DB after `transaction.rollback` is called. What should I do to rollback the transaction succcessfully and make the connection usable once again?

Btw, I also tried inserting `print connection.queries` to debug the code, and it always returns an empty list. Could it be that Django is using some other DB connection?

The code is run outside of request-response cycle. I tried switching TransactionMiddleware on and off, but it gave no effect.

I am using Django 1.1 and Postgres 8.4.

Comment: What happens if you move "transaction.commit()" in the "else" clause of the "try" statement?

Comment: Just the same behaviour.

Comment: Do you have control over the DB server? If you do turn on the query logging - "log_statement = all" (ALTER DATABASE <your_db> SET log_statement TO 'all'). Then retry it and take a look at the log.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Default TestCase does not know anything about transactions, you need to use [TransactionalTestCase](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#django.test.TransactionTestCase) in this case.

Comment: Thanks, I missed this bit of documentation!

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this decorator based on the transaction middleware [source](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/middleware/transaction.py). Hope it helps, works perfectly for me.

```
def djangoDBManaged(func):
    def f(*args, **kwargs):
        django.db.transaction.enter_transaction_management()
        django.db.transaction.managed(True)
        try:
            rs = func(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception:
            if django.db.transaction.is_dirty():
                django.db.transaction.rollback()
            django.db.transaction.leave_transaction_management()
            raise
        finally:
            if django.db.transaction.is_managed():
                if django.db.transaction.is_dirty():
                    django.db.transaction.commit()
                django.db.transaction.leave_transaction_management()
        return rs
    # So logging gets the right call info whatever the decorator order is
    f.__name__ = func.__name__
    f.__doc__ = func.__doc__
    f.__dict__ = func.__dict__
    return f
```